# What is meant by $\textbf{P}(X < x)$ in statistics?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

What is meant by $\textbf{P}(X < x)$ in statistics?

Comment: Could you provide any context? There is a range of possible answers in different levels of sophistication.

Comment: Usually, it is notation to signify the probability that a random variable $X$ is less than some number $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill assume an introductory level of knowledge on the subject:

{X<x} is an event in your sample space, namely, the event that your random variable: X takes a value less than some number: x.

P() is used as a shorthand meant to convey the expression “the probability of the event that”.

Thus $P(X<x)$ is the probability that the event {X<x} occurs.

Of course, don’t confuse this with the event that {X$\le$x} as the event {X=x} is not included in the sample space of interest. When we talk about P(X$\le$x) we are usually alluding to a cumulative distribution function (C.D.F) but that’s a more involved concept.

Comment: If X is, for instance, the number of heads in 3 tosses of a coin, then P(X<2) is the probability that the number of heads that came up was strictly less than 2. Since the inequality is strict this would actually be the same as asking P(X=0$\bigcup$X=1)

Comment: Thank you for you information.

Answer (score 1):

Here, $X$ is a random variable, and $x$ is a  number.  Then $\{X < x\}$ is an event, and $P(X < x)$ is the probability of that event.

To understand this notation, you must first find out about these notions:
"random variable"
"event"
"probability"

Answer (score 1):

It means the Probability of a random variable $X$ been lower than some specific value $x$ that the random variable $X$ can have.

As example, think in the variable $X$ as the height of some individual within your classroom, then the values the variable $X$ can have is a continuous number among all the heights the people within the class got. So, I can ask, as example, what it is the probability of choosing at random one person and their height being less than 6 ft, this can be expressed as $P(X < 6\text{ ft})$